# python xml search by attribute value

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm working on a python utility to search and present the full path to a record in a very big config file, stored as xml file.
The file size can be 12M and can hold 294460 lines, and can grow to much larger size.

Here is an example(simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root version="1.1.1">
  <record path="">
    <record path="path1">
      <field name="some_name1" value="1234"/>
      <record path="path2">
        <field name="0" value="abcd0"/>
        <field name="1" value="abcd1"/>
        <field name="2" value="abcd2"/>
        <field name="28" value="abcd28"/>
        <field name="29" value="abcd29"/>
      </record>
    </record>
    <record path="pathx">
      <record path="pathy">
        <record path="pathz">
        </record>
        <record path="pathv">
          <record path="pathw">
            <field name="some_name1" value="yes"/>
            <field name="some_name2" value="2084"/>
            <field name="some_buffer_name" value="14"/>
            <record path="cache_value">
              <field name="some_name7000" value="12"/>
            </record>
    </record>
        <record path="path_something">
          <field name="key_word1" value="8"/>
          <field name="key_word2" value="9"/>
          <field name="key_word3" value="10"/>
          <field name="key5" value="1"/>
          <field name="key6" value="1"/>
          <field name="key7" value="yes"/>
    </record>
  </record>
</root>
```

I'm interested to run on the file and file all the nodes that hold the search string in the path or field attribute of the node. Because the node "type" (or node name) can be or record or field, and thus the name of the attribute can change from path to name.

I used minidom to parse and search in the xml, but my code is taking too much resources and much too much time.

This is what I wrote:
xml_file_location is the location of the file
string_to_search is the string that I search for in the XML file
and the path to that node that I found is stored in the node of type: record , in an attribute named: path, and this is what I print to the user.

```
with open(xml_file_location, 'r') as inF:
# search the xml file for lines with the string for search
    for line in inF:
        if string_to_search in line:
            found_counter = found_counter + 1
            node_type = line.strip(" ").split(" ")[0]
            node_type = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', node_type)
            node_attr = line.strip(" ").split(" ")[1]
            node_value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', node_attr.split("=")[1])
            node_attr = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', node_attr.split("=")[0])
            #print node_type
            #print node_attr
            #print node_value
            if node_type in lines_dict:
                if not node_attr in lines_dict[node_type]:
                    lines_dict[node_type][node_attr] = [nome_value]
                elif not node_value in lines_dict[node_type][node_attr]:
                        lines_dict[node_type][node_attr].append(node_value)
            else:
                lines_dict[node_type] = {}
                lines_dict[node_type][node_attr] = [node_value]

print "Found: %s strings in the xml file" %found_counter

#pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
#pp.pprint(lines_dict)

print "Parsing the xml file"
dom = parse(xml_file_location)

print "Locating the full path"

for node_type in lines_dict:
# for all types of node
    elements = dom.getElementsByTagName(node_type)
    # create the elements for those nodes
    for node in elements:
    # go over all nodes in the elements
        if node.hasAttribute(node_attr):
            if node.getAttribute(node_attr) in lines_dict[node_type][node_attr]:
            # check if the attribute appears in the lines dict 
                result = node.getAttribute(node_attr) # holds the path
                parent = node.parentNode       # create a pointer to point on the parent node
                while parent.getAttribute("path") != "":
                # while didn't reach the root of the conf - a record that has an empty path attribute
                    result = parent.getAttribute("path") + "." + result     # add the path of the parent to the full path
                    parent = parent.parentNode                              # advance the parent pointer
                print
                print "Found: %s" %node.toprettyxml().split("\n")[0]
                print "Path:  %s" %result
```

for example:
I will search for: abcd1
the utility will print the full path: path1.path2
or I will search for: pathw and the utility will return: pathx.pathy.pathv

I understand that it's very inefficient, I go over all nodes in the config and compare them to what I put in the list_dic in the simple string search.

I tried to use external modules to do it, but without success

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this kind of search and I very appreciate the help.

Comment: You *really* do not want to use the minidom for this; use the ElementTree API instead, which supports iterative parsing. Extract just what you need, as you parse.

Comment: Read up here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm; ElementTree is part of the Python standard library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Thanks Martijn,
my first try was to use the xml.etree.ElemntTree,
but I got tangled with it, since I'm looking for a value of an attribute, and I don't know what will be the type of the attribute - will it be an attribute named "path" or "name" and in addition I don't know what is the level of the node - it can be the child of root or the child of the child of the child of root.

So I tried to alter the Xpath: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support
but couldn't alter the Element.findall() xpath expression.

Comment: Using ElemntTree, I was able to find to get to the node, but I can't go back on the the -> I can't ask the node, who is your parent.
in the syntax explanation for xpath: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax
the tables shows that using two dots ("..") I can access to the parent of the node, but until now I wasn't able to implement it.
`    parent = node.find("..")
    print parent`
parent is empty, while node is a legit node from the xml tree

Comment: ElementTree doesn't support going back up to the parent; you can install lxml, that library extends on the ElementTree API and is faster to boot.

Comment: lxml works great,
thank you very much, 
now it's only to figure out how to catch both node types records and fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I got using xpath and lxml:

`root = LXML.parse(xml_file_location)
elements_list = root.xpath(".//*[@*[contains(., $text)]]", text = string_to_search )`

The element list will catch all nodes that their attribute **value** holds the string.

using lxml `getpaerent()` method I get ask each node "who is your parent"

this is the code:

```
root = LXML.parse(xml_file_location)
elements_list = root.xpath(".//*[@*[contains(., $text)]]", text = string_to_search )
print "Found: %s strings in the xml file" %len(elements_list)
for node in elements_list:
    print "\nFound:\n%s" %LXML.tostring(node).split("\n")[0]
    parent = node.getparent()
    if node.tag == "record":
        path = node.get("path") # nodes of type: "record" hold the attribute: "path"
    elif node.tag == "field":
        path = node.get("name") # nodes of type: "field" hold the attribute: "name"
    else:
        print "unclear node type adding empty string"
        path = ""
    full_path = path
    while parent.get("path") != "":
        parent_path = parent.get("path")
        full_path = parent_path + "." + full_path
        parent = parent.getparent()
    print "Full path: %s" %full_path
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Martijn Pieters said, use ElementTree, which is in stdlib since Python 2.5 -- you're using "with" so I assume you're on 2.6+. It's easy enough to learn and its mental model is very close to the DOM.

The old-school alternative is SAX parsing, which has had a module in stdlib since forever: basically you specify callbacks to execute whenever the parser encounters opening or closing tags. It's a bit unnatural (it forces you to think in terms of text-processing, rather than XML logical structures), but can be very efficient.